# Scanner no such element exception

Tags: java

got this code:

```
private void runGame() {
    boolean won = false;

    while(won == false) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG A");
        Player p = this.nextPlayer();
        System.out.println("DEBUG B");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(p.getPlayerType() == 0) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG C");
            // is Human
            BoardPrinter.printBoard(this.b);

            // Choose figure
            BoardPrinter.printFigureChoose(this.b.getFiguresFromPlayer(p.getSymbol()),p);

            int id = this.checkInput(1,this.b.getFiguresFromPlayer(p.getSymbol()).size(),s.nextInt());
            Figure f = this.b.getFiguresFromPlayer(p.getSymbol()).get(id - 1);

            // Choose move              
            ArrayList<Move> moves = b.checkMoves(f);
            BoardPrinter.printMoveChoose(moves,p);
            int moveID = this.checkInput(1,moves.size(),s.nextInt());
            Move m = moves.get(moveID - 1);

            // Execute the chosen move
            this.b.getCellAt(f.getLocation().getX(), f.getLocation().getY()).setSymbol(Symbol.EMPTY);
            f.setLocation(m.getTarget());
            this.b.getCellAt(m.getTarget().getX(), m.getTarget().getY()).setSymbol(p.getSymbol());

            // Check win conditions
            won = this.checkVictory(p);
            System.out.println("DEBUG D");
        }
        else {
            // KI stuff

            KI k = new KI(this.b,p,p.getPlayerType());
            Move m = k.think();     

            // Execute chosen move
            Figure f = this.b.getFigureAt(m.getStart());
            this.b.getCellAt(m.getStart().getX(), m.getStart().getY()).setSymbol(Symbol.EMPTY);
            f.setLocation(m.getTarget());
            this.b.getCellAt(m.getTarget().getX(), m.getTarget().getY()).setSymbol(p.getSymbol());
        }

        // Decomment this to get debug info
        //DebugPrinter.print(this.b);

        s.close();
    }
}
```

At the moment i do get an java.util.NoSuchElementException. Yes i know what i means and i googled a lot. Still i don't understand why it get's thrown. Also, i do get my Debug output only until "C".

If i move the Scanner initialization outside of the while loop i don't get that Exception anymore. However i do get stuck to, with the Code stopping at Debug "A" and nothing else.

I've encountered this both when having 2 human players. Fun fact: The first player will always work perfectly. The Player can see the Board, choose a Figure, choose a move and execute it. Whenever the next while() run starts and the 2nd player comes into account it fails as i described it above depended on where my Scanner initialization is.

Any guesses what's the problem? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The basic rule is: if you have a `Scanner` that reads from `System.in` - better not to close it at all. The problem here is that you'll be closing not just your Scanner but a stream behind it as well.  You will not be able to reopen the stream.

Comment: I suggest the you use a **real** debugger (assuming that you use some kind of IDE, like Eclipse or similar). This way you can really see what's going on inside your code.

Comment: Which line number is this error coming from ? As I am not sure if it's coming from the Scanner. Since after closing the Scanner you reassign s to a new object.

Comment: @SoumyaKumar But the underlying stream (`System.in`) is closed, so no matter how many new scanners you try to create you'll still end up with an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You close your scanner at the end of your while loop. This means that the next time you try to read something from the scanner you'll get a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: I know, and this is why at every while() start i init the Scanner again.
while() {
init Scanner...
// do stuff
close Scanner ...
}

Comment: Once you close an input stream you can't open it again. Closing the scanner closes the underlying input stream, which in this case is `System.in`.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. So this means i have to move the Scanner init() and close() out of the while(). Got it. But then the code just stops after outputting "DEBUG A" without any error?

Comment: @Shiuyin Technically you only need to move `close()` out of the loop, since opening multiple scanners on the same input won't adversely affect anything (although it isn't really recommended either). Difficult to say what's going on without the source for `nextPlayer()`. Could you post it?